# can't figure out how to add a "total price" section to my shoping cart in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

iv'e made a shopping cart in jquery (not a real one, it's just for practicing. i know it's not secure) and i made the products to be draggable, which gives you the option to drag them from the catalog to the shopping cart. my problem is that i am trying to add a total section that will give me the total price of every product iv'e dragged into the shopping cart. iv'e tried the following code, but it did'nt work. thank you for your time.

```
<section id="productCatalog">
    <div class="product" >
        <h2 class="des">Product 1 </h2>
        <p class="description"> price: </p>
        <p class="price" id="pro1">400</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <h2 class="des">Product 2 </h2>
        <p class="description"> price: </p>
        <p class="price" id="pro2">200</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <h2 class="des">Product 3 </h2>
        <p class="description"> price: </p>
        <p class="price" id="pro3">900</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <h2 class="des">Product 4 </h2>
        <p class="description"> price: </p>
        <p class="price" id="pro4">152.30</p>
    </div>
   </section>
   <section id="shoppingCart">
    <h2 align="center">shopping cart</h2>
    total:
    <span id="cartSum">0</span>
   </section>

<script>
    $(function(){


        $('.product').draggable({ 
            scroll: false, 
            containment: 'document' , 
            revert: true,
            start: function()
            {
                contents = $(this).text();
            }
         });    


           var price = parseInt($(".selected").text()); 
          var cartSum = $("#cartSum").text();



          $('#shoppingCart').droppable({ hoverClass: 'border', accept: '.product', drop: function()
          {

             $('#shoppingCart').append("<div  class='selected'>" + contents + "</div>" + "<button id='butt' onclick='one(this)'>delete item</button>" ) ;
             cartSum = price;
             function updateCartTotal(){
            $("#cartSum").text(cartSum); 

        }
          }}); 

          window.one = function(obj){

        var item = $(obj).prev().andSelf().remove(); 


    }

    });
</script>
```

also i'm including the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kshayk/QbNtX/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QbNtX/4/

Comment: thanks that works! but half way, if i'm deleting something the total remains. any suggestions?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QbNtX/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write a two separate functions here -- one to sum up the prices and the other to display that sum. Below I am assuming there is a wrapper around each price in your #shoppingCart. This is often good practice because it lets you avoid unnecessary processing and will make your code cleaner:

```
function getTotalCost() {
  var totalPrice = 0;
  $("#shoppingCart").find(".price").each(function() {
    totalPrice += parseFloat($(this).html());
  });
  return totalPrice;
}

function updateCartTotal() {
  $("#cartSum").html( getTotalCost() );
}
```

And then it is just a matter of updating the `#cartSum` when the "cart" is updated; I'd recommend using [jQuery's draggable's "stop" event](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop), which is triggered when the dragging stops:

```
$('.product').draggable({ 
  stop: updateCartTotal       
});
```

And since in your case you have a "delete" button as well, you should update the cart if anything is deleted:

```
var buttonHTML = "... <button id='butt' onclick='one(this); updateCartTotal();'>delete item</button>" 
$('#shoppingCart').append(buttonHTML) ;
```

---

**However**, after deleting a lot of the old clutter from your code, I found it cleaner just to update the #shoppingCart sum in the "droppable" event (although either event works). The core of the changes can be seen below:

```
...

$(document).on("click", ".deleteButton", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    updateCartTotal();
});


$('#shoppingCart').droppable({
    hoverClass: 'border',
    accept: '.product',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var price = $(ui.draggable).find(".price").html();
        var item = $(ui.draggable).find(".des").html();
        var deleteButton = "<button class='deleteButton'>Delete</button>";
        var newCartEntry = "<div class='selected'>" + item +
            "<span class='price'>" + price + "</span>" + deleteButton +
            "</div>";
        $('#shoppingCart').append(newCartEntry);
        updateCartTotal();
    }
});

...
```

Here's a [Fiddle that describes what I mean](http://jsfiddle.net/4Zr25/3/).

Comment: hey, can you use it in my jsfiddle becuase i can't quite understan how it works. thant you :)

Comment: Fiddle has been added.